# Custom module controller not working

Tags: magento2

I have added a sample custom module in Magento 2. I have two controller function for admin panel page,

```
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin_magento2/sample/index/index/
http://127.0.0.1/magento2/admin_magento2/sample/sampletwo/index/
```

First url only display page. The second one displays 404 or redirecting to dashboard.

Please help me someone to solve this.

**Note**

I have added admin panel menu for first url only.

Answer (score 0):

When attempting to access modules/functionality in the backend (Adminhtml), Magento checks for the presence of the secret `Form Keys`, and if/when someone does attempt to access an action and doesn't supply a valid FormKey and/or supplies an Invalid FormKey - the Adminhtml AbstractAction (Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction) will route the user Admin UIX defined Startup page (which is usually the Dashboard page)

[This mechanism serves a "security checkpoint" to prevent users from accessing portions of the Backend that they don't have access to]

---

To prevent the check for FormKey you have two options:

*(a) Turn off FormKey Validation*

**Navigation:** Stores -> Settings : Configuration -> Advanced : Admin -> Security -> Setup "Add Secret Key to URLs" to "No"

It's very important to remember that doing so will turn off Secret Key Validation, and therefore *may* make your application vulnerable.

[image: How To Turn Off FormKey Validation]

*(b) Turn off FormKey Validation for your controller*

Specify the action(s) you wish to exempt, from the FormKey check, in the "$_publicActions" attribute of your Admin Controller.

**protected $_publicActions = ['ENTER_NAME_OF_ACTION'];**

Code Example:

```
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $_publicActions = ['index'];

    public function execute()
    {
        echo "My Hello World! Controller";
    }

}
```

---

When accessing options from the Admin UIX Menu - Magento will automatically add the FormKey for you. That is why you are able to access the first URL v/s not able to access the second URL.